# How to calculate the percentage using facet in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am calculating the notification percentage in my app for tracking some statistics.

My Collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: "123",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "589"
  },
  {
    _id: "223",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "589"
  },
  {
    _id: "474",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "589"
  },
  {
    _id: "875",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "112"
  },
  {
    _id: "891",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "112"
  }
]
```

Expected Result:

Here we can see that, `UserId - 589` has received 3 notifications out of which 2 are seen. So the calculation is `(totalNumOfSeen/totalNumOfNoticationsSent) * 100`

```
[{
    userId: "589",
    notificationPercentage : 66.66
},{
    userId: "112",
    notificationPercentage : 50
}]
```

I am using a facet for grouping and matching but that is returning me an array of object and I am not getting how to perform divide on this.

My Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      totalNumOfSeen: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: "589",
            status: "seen"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$userId",
            totalNumOfSeen: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      totalNumOfNoticationsSent: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: "589",
            
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$userId",
            totalNumOfNoticationsSent: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

The Above Query is giving me the below Result:

```
[
  {
    "totalNumOfNoticationsSent": [
      {
        "_id": "589",
        "totalNumOfNoticationsSent": 3
      }
    ],
    "totalNumOfSeen": [
      {
        "_id": "589",
        "totalNumOfSeen": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

MongoPlayground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHn2ZlshgDL

Now I need to add one more field as `notificationPercentage` and calculate the notification percentage based on the above facet result. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by `userId` and get `totalSeen` count using `$cond` if `status` is `seen`, get total count of notification using `$sum`,
- `$project` to show required fields, and calculate percentage using `$divide` and `$multiply`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      totalSeen: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "seen"] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      userId: "$_id",
      notificationPercentage: {
        $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$totalSeen", "$total"] }, 100]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ko2a8xCkhcJ)