# How to get the documents based on Date Filters(Week, Month and Custom Dates) in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to fetch all the documents based on date filters as below in MongoDB:

1. This Week only
2. Last Week only
3. This Month only
4. Last Month only
5. Between Custom Dates.

My collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: "123",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "589",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-11-17T04:35:29.646Z"),
  },
  {
    _id: "223",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "589",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-11-17T04:35:29.646Z"),
  },
  {
    _id: "474",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "589",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-11-10T04:35:29.646Z"),

  },
  {
    _id: "875",
    status: "seen",
    userId: "112",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-10-11T04:35:29.646Z"),
  },
  {
    _id: "891",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "112",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-10-11T04:35:29.646Z"),
  },
  {
    _id: "891",
    status: "unseen",
    userId: "113",
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-11-09T04:35:29.646Z"),
  }]
```

Expected Result:

1. When This_Week Filter is applied - fetch all the userIds whose createdAt falls in this week and then calculate the notification percentage.

```
  [{
    userId : "589",
    notificationPercentage: 100% // Because userId 589 has 2 seen documents for this week.
  }]
```

2. When This_Month filter is applied: -  userId 589 and userId 113 was created in this month and calculating the notificationPercentage for it.

```
[{
  userId : "589",
  notificationPercentage: 66.66% 
},
{
  userId : "113",
  notificationPercentage: 0% 
}]
```

3. When Last_month filter is applied:

```
[{
  userId : "112",
  notificationPercentage: 50% //Because only userId 112 was created in last month and finding the notification percentage for it.
}]
```

4. When Last_week filter is applied:

```
[{
  userId : "113",
  notificationPercentage: 0% //Because only userId 113 was created in last week and finding the notification percentage for it.
},
{
  userId : "589",
  notificationPercentage: 0% //Because only userId 113 was created in last week and finding the notification percentage for it.
}]
```

Formula for notification percentage -
`(No of times the user has seen/no of times he got notifications) * 100`

Comment: Check the docs. You have an operator for each of those operations

Comment: @minsky, I am not able to find it in the Mongo document. If possible, can u please share the link for its section.

Comment: sure https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/index.html

Comment: Can you post some sampe document that you hve

Comment: Hi @varman.... you can refer the sample documents from the question ----> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852459/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-using-facet-in-mongodb  ....I have to calculate the average by grouping the userIds as asked in this question. But now I have one more field (createdAt) which will have the date for every document and I need filter by thisWeek, prevWeek, thisMonth and prevMonth

Comment: @sinr This is a new question, so you need to post the respective details here. You can't point another question. Because in future some one will refer this and they will be confused. And you haven't  mentioned the format of createdAt too

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look @varman

Comment: @sinr sorry for the late reply, bit busy

Comment: That's okay np. Thank you for the help @varman :) It is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some thing like following. Use match operation to filter out. In this example I have shown you the last_week details. I checked all scenarios that you mentioned above. And its working fine

```
[{$match: {
  $expr:{
    $and:[
      {$gt:["$createdAt",new Date(new Date()-14*60*60*24*1000)]},
      {$lt:["$createdAt",new Date(new Date()-7*60*60*24*1000)]}
      ]
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: '$userId',
  totalSeen: {
    $sum: {
      $cond: [
        {
          $eq: [
            '$status',
            'seen'
          ]
        },
        1,
        0
      ]
    }
  },
  total: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}}, {$project: {
  _id: 0,
  userId: '$_id',
  notificationPercentage: {
    $multiply: [
      {
        $divide: [
          '$totalSeen',
          '$total'
        ]
      },
      100
    ]
  }
}}]
```